Trouble loading a keras model in tfjs-node
(I'm using Python 3.11.7, tensorflow 2.16.1, and tfjs-node@4.18.0)
I have found this model on github called opennsfw2 and I would like to use it in a Node server. There are no saved model files provided, so I had to export it in Python like so:
import opennsfw2

model = opennsfw2.make_open_nsfw_model()
model.export('opennsfw2')

I'm not sure if that's the proper way to export a SavedModel, but I was able to load the created files back in Python and inference works as expected.
Then I wanted to load the model in node.js:
import * as tfjs from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node";

const model = await tfjs.node.loadSavedModel("./models/opennsfw2");

I've done this with other models in the past with no issues, but this one raises an exception:
E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:903] tfg_optimizer{} failed: NOT_FOUND: Op type not registered 'DisableCopyOnRead' in binary running on LAPTOP. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
        While importing FunctionDef: __inference__traced_save_11547
        when importing GraphDef to MLIR module in GrapplerHook
E tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_util.cc:630] NodeDef mentions attribute debug_name which is not in the op definition: Op<name=VarHandleOp; signature= -> resource:resource; attr=container:string,default=""; attr=shared_name:string,default=""; attr=dtype:type; attr=shape:shape; attr=allowed_devices:list(string),default=[]; is_stateful=true> This may be expected if your graph generating binary is newer  than this binary. Unknown attributes will be ignored. NodeDef: {{node Variable}}
I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:212] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: ./models/opennsfw2
E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:903] tfg_optimizer{} failed: NOT_FOUND: Op type not registered 'DisableCopyOnRead' in binary running on LAPTOP. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
        While importing FunctionDef: __inference__traced_save_11547
        when importing GraphDef to MLIR module in GrapplerHook
I tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:301] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 1504673 microseconds.
C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:435
        return this.binding.loadSavedModel(path, tags);
                            ^

Error: Failed to load SavedModel: Converting GraphDef to Graph has failed with an error: 'Op type not registered 'DisableCopyOnRead' in binary running on LAPTOP. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.' The binary trying to i
    at NodeJSKernelBackend.loadSavedModelMetaGraph (C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\nodejs_kernel_backend.js:435:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\saved_model.js:448:45)
    at step (C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\saved_model.js:49:23)
    at Object.next (C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\saved_model.js:30:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\dev\Projects\nsfw_test\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\saved_model.js:21:58)

I read something about how this could be a version incompatibility error, but I also exported the model under tensorflow 2.14.0 (the earliest version allowed by the opennsfw2 package) and that didn't change anything.
I'm not even sure if this is an issue that could be fixed with changes to the exporting of the model, or if the SavedModel is fine and this is just an issue with tfjs-node. Any help would be appreciated

Hi @FinnCoal,you are facing a version incompatibility issue between  tfjs-node and tensorflow version, please update your tfjs-node which is compatible with tensorflow version.If possible, modify the model in Python to avoid using deprecated ops like DisableCopyOnRead,Thanks.
